# How to force rvm to use older versions of llvm to install rubinius on arch?

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm, llvm

I have been having trouble installing rubinius on arch through rvm. Rubinius requires llvm version of 3.0-3.5 however Arch provides 3.6 by default under the package name llvm and I can install llvm35 to provide llvm 3.5. How do I force rvm to use llvm35 instead of using llvm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
./configure --llvm-config=/path/to/llvm-config
```

I don't have Arch installed, so I don't know where the `llvm35` package puts `llvm-config`. Hopefully, this gives you enough of a hint to continue; if not, please let me know and I'll see what I can do.